# Multiple protobuf package versions of c# service

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a protobuf file with v1 package version:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package greet.v1;

service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

I have v1 and v2 versions of corresponding service:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    // Implements greet.v1.Greeter
    endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterServiceV1>();

    // Implements greet.v2.Greeter
    endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterServiceV2>();
});
```

How to set v2 package version? By second protobuf file? Or should I just change v1 to v2? Could multiple versions services work together as one protobuf file generate just only one file with
`static readonly string __ServiceName = "standing.v1.Greeter"` or `static readonly string __ServiceName = "standing.v2.Greeter"` depending on package version.